# Join query on 3 tables is not working properly in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm working with php mysql and I have joined 3 tables: `demanddraft`,  `payonline` and `registration`. Now I want to get the values from these three table according to campus course and exam date.

The *registration* table has three fields: `campus1`, `course1` and `examdate`, according to which we have to take the value from table *demanddraft* and *payonline*. I want to get the value of `status=success` from payonline table and `ddstatus=approved` from demanddraft table. But unable to fetch desired records.

Here is my query:

```
$sql= "select * from programme prog 
join demanddraft dem ON prog.stuid = dem.stuid 
join payonline pay ON pay.stuid = prog.stuid  
where ((pay.status='success' || dem.ddstatus='Approved') 
&& prog.campus1='".$campus1."') && prog.course1='".$course1."'
&&  prog.examdate='".$examdate."'";
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what error does your mysql server throws?

Comment: And you are using 'Approved', May this be 'approved'?

Comment: @Ali:there is no error but few records are missing e.g i have 194 students as success in payonline table and 9 students as approved in demendraft table so total should be 203 but my query giving me 183.

Comment: @cubuzoa : no dear its Approved in database table.

Comment: a left join may be required

Comment: You used inner join. This may filter your result if any null records on left or right table. Try left or right join according to your needs

Comment: @cubuzoa : i have tried both left and right join in place of join but on applying left join the records decreased and on applying right join in place of join the records remain same.

Comment: Run the join first and then add filter one by one and test. Without data is difficult to find exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no error but few records are missing e.g i have 194 students
>   as success in payonline table and 9 students as approved in demendraft
>   table so total should be 203 but my query giving me 183

That might be your actual result.
As i see you have where ((pay.status='success' || dem.ddstatus='Approved') 
&& prog.campus1='".$campus1."'). So, yes, you can have 194 in pay table and 9 in dem table, but that does not mean that all of them have prog.campus1='".$campus1."' . Or any of the next WHERE conditions.

Would be very good if you can post your tables, and the data somewhere like http://sqlfiddle.com/ so we can run the query and browse your data ( 200 records is not that much )

Comment: i have changed my query to $sql= "select * from programme prog join demanddraft dem ON prog.stuid = dem.stuid left join payonline pay ON pay.stuid = prog.stuid  where (pay.status='success' || dem.ddstatus='Approved')  && prog.campus1='".$campus1."' && prog.course1='".$course1."' &&  prog.examdate='".$examdate."'";
and dear the status will be approved or success in both the table if the students fill their all records so these where clause feilds cant be empty.

Comment: unable to build the sqlfiddle i will send you my tables on your mail id please send me your id